# JavaScript new objects inside objects duplicating

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I'm taking an adventure into the depths of JavaScript and have come across a little problem that I can't get my head around.

Everything I know about programming is self taught, this problem might have some terminology behind it I have never heard of, so I don't know what it would be called.

I'll explain the problem I am experiencing.

I've been writing a framework for HTML5 canvas for displaying 2d and 3d graphics.

As you might expect, I have designed an element class, these elements have positions on the canvas which are built from a vector class I put together.

The problem I'm having is, if I make two "Text" objects, then call a function inside their position object, all the positions of the "Text" objects change to this value:

```
    var usernameLabel = new C.Text('Username:');
    usernameLabel.position.set(30,30)

    var username = new C.Text('Hello World');
    username.position.set(0,70)

    console.log(usernameLabel.position.x) // 0 when it should be 30
```

I'm sure there is something I missed, I just can't figure out what.

```
    C.Text.prototype = new C.Element();

    C.Element.position = new JC.Vector();
```

Any help would be most appreciated!

This is my full Element class

```
C.elements = 0;

C.Element = function()
{
    this.id = C.elements ++;

    this.position = new C.Vector();
    this.rotation = new C.Vector();
    this.style = new C.Style();

    this.children = [];
}

C.Element.prototype = {

    constructor : C.Element,

    addChildObject : function( o )
    {
        return this.children.push(o);
    },

    removeChildObject : function( o )
    {
        this.children.splice(o,1);
    }

}
```

Text class

```
C.Text = function(string)
{
    this.string = string || '';
}

C.Text.prototype = new C.Element();
C.Text.prototype.constructor = C.Text();
```

I also have more classes built from C.Element obviously, for example:

```
C.Rectangle = function(width, height)
{
    this.style.setSize(width,height);
}

C.Rectangle.prototype = new C.Element();
C.Rectangle.prototype.constructor = new C.Rectangle();



var usernameLabel = new C.Text('Username:');
usernameLabel.position.set(30,30) // 0,70?

var username = new C.Text('');
username.position.set(0,70) // 0,70

var rect = new C.Rectangle(20,0);
rect.position.set(30,80) // 90,80?

var rect2 = new C.Rectangle(20,0);
rect2.position.set(90,80) // 90,80
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer! Thanks for the help! The solution was to make the parent object do a call

for a reason I don't fully understand.

```
C.Text = function(string)
{
    C.Object.call(this)

    this.string = string || '';
    return this;
}

C.Text.prototype = new C.Object();
C.Text.prototype.constructor = C.Text;
```

Answer (score 1):

From the looks of it, you are declaring position as a 'static' variable on the object, which means it will change. To make it change only on a specific object you need one of the following:

```
C.Element.prototype.position = new JC.Vector();
```

or inside a function within the object

```
this.position = new JC.Vector();
```

These declarations are for items that are specific to the object, where as the `C.Element.position` declaration is for something that will be the same in all instances of the object.

**Update**

Instead of declaring `C.Text.prototype = new C.Element()`. Try using `C.Text.prototype = C.Element.prototype`. Hopefully that will fix your problem. Instead of creating a new object to base it on, it bases it directly on the prototype of `C.Element`

Comment: @user4030 post it to jsBin or jsFiddle and I can take a look at it. It will be hard to read here.

Comment: I added the full class in the description.

Comment: Then I'll add my text class aswell:

Comment: @user4030 Updated again. This should be a fix. Tested it out with some test code and it worked fine.

Comment: Now it does not call the constructor. It skips the call to C.Element() constructor and this.position is never added to the object.

Comment: @user4030 This is expected. You will need to manually call this. You can do this a number of different ways, but my recommendation would be to, before you set the new constructor, set `C.Text.prototype._constructor = C.Text.prototype.constructor`. Then just call `this._constructor()` in your method. Note that this will prevent multiple constructor inheritance.

Comment: I found the answer! Thanks for the help! The solution was to make the parent object do a call for a reason I don't fully understand.

`C.Text = function(string)
    {
     C.Element.call(this)
    
     this.string = string || '';
     return this;
    }

    C.Text.prototype = new C.Object();
    C.Text.prototype.constructor = C.Text;`